# Регулярное выражение удаления между двумя символами

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка с именами, но между ними есть символы и их надо удалить.
Строка выглядит так `Иванов;#576;#Петров;#34;#Соколов`
И надо составить регулярку для `с#` чтобы выглядело так `Иванов;Петров;Соколов`
Тоесть по сути нужно удалить `#` и то что между ними.

Пробовал использовать регулярку `\#(.*)\#`, но она выделяет текст от первой до последней `#`. При удаление получается так Иванов;Соколов.

Comment: ок, а в чем заключается вопрос? что-нибудь пытались сами?

Comment: Я пытался делать регулярку `/#(.*)\#` но она берет текст от первой и до последней `#`. Короче проще сказать не знаю как написать так чтобы удалилось как в примере.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос то что пытались и описание что не работало

Comment: Кажется, вы хотите вручную заменить работу парсера. В каком _формате_ ваши входные данные?

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае нужно либо конкретизировать регулярное выражение, например между ## могут быть только цифры и `;`

```
var s = "Иванов;#576;#Петров;#34;#Соколов";
var ss = Regex.Replace(s, @"#\d*;#", "");
```

либо добавить ленивости в регулярное выражение

```
var s = "Иванов;#576;#Петров;#34;#Соколов";
var ss = Regex.Replace(s, @"#.*?#", "");
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло. Я думаю не важно что находится между `#`.

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось с таким шаблоном

```
pattern = "(#[^#]+#)";
```